# transit opacity of one and rotate of another element of the same size

Tags: html, css

this problem is getting me crazy:

I am trying to rotate a circle border of one element and i want to change at the same moment the opacity of the circle inlay while the user hovers over the circle. My problem at my current setup only the opacity is changing:

```
<div id="main-circle">
<a class="circle-container" href="#">
<div class="circle-border"></div>
<div class="image-overlay" style="background-image:url(http://manuel-haug.de/img/circle-placeholder.png)"></div>
<div class="circle-overlay"></div>
</a>
</div>
```

When i change the order of the elements like this:

```
<div id="main-circle">
<a class="circle-container" href="#">
<div class="image-overlay" style="background-image:url(img/circle-placeholder.png)"></div>
<div class="circle-overlay"></div>
<div class="circle-border"></div>
</a>
```

Than the border is rotating but the inlay isn't visible.

My css code:

```
.circle-container
{
    position: relative;
    left: 0px;
    top: 0px;
    -webkit-transform: translate3d(0px, 0px, 0px);
    width:156px;
    height:156px;
    overflow: hidden;
    -webkit-transition-property: -webkit-transform, opacity;
    -moz-transition-property: -moz-transform, opacity;
    -ms-transition-property: -ms-transform, opacity;
    -o-transition-property: -o-transform, opacity;
    transition-property: transform, opacity;
    -webkit-transition-duration: 0.8s;
    -moz-transition-duration: 0.8s;
    -ms-transition-duration: 0.8s;
    -o-transition-duration: 0.8s;
    transition-duration: 0.8s;  
    margin: 0px 52px 60px 52px;
    float: left;
    cursor: pointer;
    display: block;
    z-index: 2;
    padding: 0;
    border: 0;
    outline: 0;
    font-size: 100%;
    vertical-align: baseline;
    background: transparent;
}
.circle-border
{
    background:url(http://manuel-haug.de/img/circle-border.png) center center no-repeat;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0px;
    left: 0px;

    text-align: center;
    -webkit-transition-duration: 0.5s;
    -moz-transition-duration: 0.5s;
    -o-transition-duration: 0.5s;
    transition-duration: 0.5s;
    -moz-transition: all 1s ease;
    -webkit-transition: all 1s ease;
    -o-transition: all 1s ease;
    transition: all 1s ease;
    -webkit-transition-property: -webkit-transform;
    -moz-transition-property: -moz-transform;
    -o-transition-property: -o-transform;
    transition-property: transform;
}
.circle-border:hover
{
    -webkit-transform:rotate(45deg);
    -moz-transform:rotate(45deg); 
    -o-transform:rotate(45deg);
}
.circle-overlay
{
    background:url(http://manuel-haug.de/img/circle-overlay.png) center center no-repeat;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0%;
    left: 0%;
    zoom: 1;
    -ms-filter:"progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Alpha(Opacity=0)";
    -moz-opacity:0;
    -khtml-opacity: 0;
    opacity: 0;
    filter: alpha(opacity=0);


    -webkit-transition-duration: 0.5s;
    -moz-transition-duration: 0.5s;
    -o-transition-duration: 0.5s;
    transition-duration: 0.5s;
    -moz-transition: all 1s ease;
    -webkit-transition: all 1s ease;
    -o-transition: all 1s ease;
    transition: all 1s ease;

}
.circle-overlay:hover
{
    -moz-opacity:0.9;
    -khtml-opacity: 0.9;
    opacity: 0.9;
}
.image-overlay
{
    overflow: hidden; 
    border-top-left-radius: 75px; 
    border-top-right-radius: 75px; 
    border-bottom-right-radius: 75px; 
    border-bottom-left-radius: 75px; 
    background-position: 50% 50%; 
    background-repeat: initial initial;
    width: 96%;
    height: 96%;
    -webkit-border-radius: 50%;
    -moz-border-radius: 50%;
    border-radius: 50%;
    position: absolute;
    top: 2%;
    left: 2%;
    text-align: center;
}
```

To see a example of my problem i have created a [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/NYNSX/1/)

Hope someone can help me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You were rotating the border on hover of `.circle-border`.. (`.circle-border:hover`).

Just change it so that the border of `.circle-border` is rotated when hovering over the parent element, in this case you would use `.circle-container:hover .circle-border`.

[**Working Example**](http://jsfiddle.net/P5vWj/)

```
.circle-container:hover .circle-border {
    -webkit-transform:rotate(45deg);
    -moz-transform:rotate(45deg);
    -o-transform:rotate(45deg);
}
```